# I don't get how these connectors for furniture are supposed to hold together?

Tags: furniture

How is there a strong connection formed here? It is clear to me how you install it, but how does the bigger piece form a connection with the screw-like one? You just rotate it, would it not simply push the long piece to the side? How is this secure?
[image]

Comment: Oran, Welcome to the world of boxed furniture and cabinets.  Sometimes you have to trust the process.  They have been using this method for 40 years.

Comment: @RMDman Is this not used outside of mass-produced "boxed" furniture? If so, why?

Comment: This type of connection method lends itself well to machined wood parts as are common in mass production.  It is actually  more difficult to drill, position and align the necessary holes  needed for these "screw and cam" fasteners when building something by hand.  These fasteners are also good for the end user to work with as they need very little tools, thus appealing to the many that don't want to purchase , or have a need for anything but basic tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The head of the part with the screw threads is captured by the "forks" on the rotating cam part, and the increasing thickness of the cam part then pulls the connection tight.

Of course, the parts must be pushed close enough together for that to happen, and the cam part must be correctly aligned with the open side permitting the head to enter.

*If you are using them in a piece you are building, (as opposed to the typical "assembling mass-produced furniture") the location of the blind hole the cam part goes into and the mating hole for the unthreaded end of the threaded part (as well as the pilot for the place where it screws in on the mating part) are fairly critical. It can certainly be done, with care.*

Comment: It helps to think of the cam as a wedge, except the wedge part is basically a spiral.  You push the wedge in, and it tightens between the screw head and the board.